# Can I exclude physics engine from my Unity Build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating game in Unity 5.3 where I am not doing anything with respective to Physics. There is no gameobject which has RigidBody or any Collider. Its just a simple game. As I am not going to use Physics Engine, can I exclude it from my Android/IOS build? As I want to make apk/ipa file as small as possible.

Comment: It's a good qustsion. I'm pretty sure you can NOT do that.  Its too inherent: also it's not that big.  Google 10000000 articles on making Unity builds smaller.   Choose the smaller .Net

Answer (score 0):

The physics is not what is taking the more space in the game, the textures have a significantly bigger memory space usage. Plus I don't think Unity is going to export every single package in your game. If you do not use the packages included in the physics engine, there's no reason for it to import it I think.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, when building for iOS or WebGL (unsure of android), you can select to strip engine code, which removes any unused modules. More info on that is in this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html
(Scroll down to the Stripping with IL2CPP section)

However, according to the page, the option replaces another if the IL2CPP scripting backend is used. You may not have that installed, so you'll need to use the Unity download assistant to install that Unity Editor Module.